# What view controller navigation strategy is the iOS Photos app using?

Tags: ios, user-interface

When you open up the Photos app on your iOS device, a collection view of all the photos on that device shows.

What I'm interested in knowing is how, when you tap one picture, you are able to swipe between all your pictures that were shown in the previous collection view. Is the new view controller that you see after tapping a single picture put onto the navigation stack, because there is a back button?

I'm mostly curious about the swiping through pictures functionality. How is that done? Is it another collection view but with paging, and each cell size's width in this new collection view is the width of the frame of the view controller?

If possible, relevant code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not A navigation Stack, More Like a Scroll View is Used with paging enabled, where the images are Loaded in the Scrollview and then Viewed accordingly.. you can use this tutorial to get started, It explains in detail about scrolling,Zomming and paging properties of a scrollview http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content

Answer (score 1):

I believe what Apple is doing in their Photos app is using the new layout to layout navigation transition to do a push between two controllers with UICollectionViews. If you set the useLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions property to yes, you can do a custom animation for your push transition. You'll notice that going back from the single picture view to the collection, you can pinch it closed, and see the navigation bar fade from one look to another. If you want to learn more about this, you should check out the WWDC 2013 video, "Custom Transitions Using View Controllers" (session 218).